# How to increase timeout for MongoDB query with an equivalent function as maxTimeMS for V2.4?

Tags: mongodb, timeout

The `maxTimeMS()` method is a feature of V2.6 that allows users to set a MS time before a query is killed. Is there an equivalent feature or methodology in V2.4 that allows users to set this for all our queries, to prevent a long running query from killing the DB processes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "increase timeout", just don't pass anything in 2.4 and you'll get the infinite timeout that is there by default.